# SSMA for MySQL only loads the first thirteen tables?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-migration-assi

I am using SQL Server Migration Assistant for MySQL v5.3.0 and I am able to connect to MySQL and see my database.  The problem is that I only see the first thirteen tables in my MySQL database? 
[image: SSMA]

There are actually over a thousand tables:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found it:
"I solved the issue. The problem was the value of the Data migration timeout in minutes property.

Go to Tools > Project Settings > General and in the left pane click on Migration and then in the right pane, in the section Misc, change Data migration timeout in minutes property to something larger (the default value was 15; I changed it to 300)."
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29688/error-migrating-a-big-table-from-mysql-to-sql-server-2012